# Trick for reducing a specific polynomial.

Tags: abstract-algebra, polynomials, factoring, quartics

Let $f(x) = x^4 − x^3 + 2x^2 − 3x − 3$

Show that f(x) is reducible over $\Bbb{Q}$

Rational zeros shows there is no roots i tried writing $(x^2+bx+c)(x^2+dx+e)$ and then tried to solve the equations for each of letters but it got crazy ugly which lead me to the conclusion there must be a better way...

Comment: There is a typo in the title of your question. Please fix it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

i think that is a good idea, it is $$(x^2+3)(x^2-x-1)=f(x)$$

Comment: Any particular insight or just fortune and experience?

Comment: i have made the same as you $$(x^2+ax+b)(x^2+cx+d)$$

Comment: Dam, ok surprised theirs not a better way, thanks though.

Comment: there are also formulas to factor such polynomials

Answer (score 1):

Also, we can use the following way.

For all real $k$ we obtain:
$$x^4-x^3+2x^2-3x-3=\left(x^2-\frac{1}{2}x+k\right)^2-\frac{1}{4}x^2-k^2-2kx^2+kx+2x^2-3x-3=$$
$$=\left(x^2-\frac{1}{2}x+k\right)^2-\left(\left(2k-\frac{7}{4}\right)x^2-(k-3)x+k^2+3\right).$$
Now we'll choose a value of $k$ such that $2k-\frac{7}{4}>0$ and $$(k-3)^2-4\left(2k-\frac{7}{4}\right)(k^2+3)=0.$$
Easy to see that $k=1$ is valid.

Id est, $$x^4-x^3+2x^2-3x-3=\left(x^2-\frac{1}{2}x+1\right)^2-\left(\frac{1}{4}x^2+2x+4\right)=$$
$$=\left(x^2-\frac{1}{2}x+1\right)^2-\left(\frac{1}{2}x+2\right)^2=(x^2-x-1)(x^2+3).$$